# How to determine the characteristic equation of $y''' + By' + C = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the problem involved only $y''' + By' = 0$, then we can easily solved this since its characteristic equation is $r^3 + Br = 0$. What if we have $y''' + By' + C = 0$, how do we determine its characteristic equation?

B and C are constants.

Comment: This is just an inhomogeneous equation, $y''' + B y' = -C$.

Comment: Hint: Write down the differential equation solved by `z=y+(C/B)t`. (If `B=0`, solve directly `y'''=-C`.)

Comment: Is C a constant or function in the variable of $y$?

Comment: C is a constant, B is also a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Your equation is a [non-homogeneous equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Nonhomogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients) and its general solution  is the sum of the general solution of the related homogeneous equation and a particular solution.

You know how to find the general solution of the homogeneous equation
$$
y'''+by'=0
$$

and, in this case , a particular solution is easy to find :

$$
y=\frac{-c}{b}x
$$

Answer (score 1):

As others said, this is a non-homogeneous equation. To determine the characteristic equation, you just need to consider the homogenous part, $y'''+By'$.

Hence,

$$r^3+Br=0.$$